# connection to node terminated during authentication - kafka

Tags: authentication, ssl, apache-kafka

connection to node terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient

Answer (score 0):

this is a very generic error. if we enable debug logs that would help with why the authentication problems are happening. 
Go to log4j.properties file in your config directory of kafka and set the logs to DEBUG instead of INFO.

Like below change INFO to DEBUG. this would help in figuring out what exactly is the issue with respect to why SSL connections are failing .

Like a certificate issue 
or unsigned certificate 
then it makes it easier to solve and debug further.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, kafkaAppender

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=/var/log/kafka/kafka-controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=/var/log/kafka/kafka.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=/var/log/kafka/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=/var/log/kafka/kafka-state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=INFO, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false

log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

log4j.logger.org.IOItec.zkclient.ZkClient=INFO

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=INFO, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false
```